# Use Google Fit to store raw accelerometer data

Tags: wear-os, android-sensors, google-fit

I've been experimenting with querying raw accelerometer data from an Android Wear (Moto360) watch but it seems to drain too much battery (about 15% per hour). Presumably this is because the Moto360 does not support batching of sensor data. I was wondering if the Google Fit Sensor's API can be used to intelligently store accelerometer data (x,y,z) in the Fitness Store. So far I've only come across storing activity types and not raw sensor data. I am looking for a battery efficient solution.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: i want access to raw sensor data to run some gesture recognition algorithm i'm developing.

Comment: Surly doing the recognition live in real time if possible and saving just the results is the way to go.  Pushing tons of data to the cloud just to do recognition stuff on it that is not related to fitness stuff is not going to be at all battery friendly.

Comment: Is it possible to attach an event ( like a step.. or an specific accelerometer movement ) to activate raw data accelerometer during a short time (like 1 minute), save it and then process or save all Raw Accelerometer data with Google Fit?
 That would save a lot of battery and would allow to process that recognition.